# What is tensor representation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I am reading a paper and I could not understand the tensor representation. In this paper, it is given as follow.

Let $A$ be a finite dim. algebra over a field $k$. Let $m:A \otimes_k A \rightarrow A$ be the multiplication map and $f : A \rightarrow k$ be a linear functional. Let us choose a basis $e_1,\cdots,e_n$ for $A$ and corresponding tensor representations $m_{ij}^{k}$ and $f_i$ for $m$ and $f$, respectively. And it goes on...

What does tensor representation mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just means that $m(e_i\otimes e_j) = \sum_k m_{i,j}^ke_k$ and $f(e_i)=f_i$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in trouble with the “index notation”, this can help you: 
https://youtu.be/wXZWi5ehloU